# Python fitting lognormal to a histogram

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

I'd like to fit a lognormal distribution to some data, but I'm having trouble. I'm trying to use scipy.stats lognorm to fit to my data, I currently have:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib at plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

data = genfromtext('data.txt')
plt.hist(data, bins=np.logspace(0,5,200))
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.show()

shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(data)
pdf = sp.stats.lognorm.pdf(data, shape, loc, scale)

plt.plot(data,pdf)

plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

The histogram looks good... [image] But I get a second plot with the pdf that looks like nonsense:[image]

Once I have the parameters shape, loc and scale, I'd like to use this pdf to randomly generate data that follows this distribution.

The application is a simulation that generates some random objects using `np.random.uniform(min,max)` but I'd like to use a more realistic distribution. I've found my data file from a reputable source online which represents exactly what I want to generate. So now all I need is the lognormal fit.

Before you ask 'why dont you just randomly pick data from your file?', I would do this, but I want to generate tens of thousands of representative objects, my data file is only 3000 in length.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use the `rvs()` method of `lognorm` to generate random samples.

Comment: *"I'd like to fit a lognormal distribution to some data, but I'm having trouble."*  What is the trouble that you are having fitting the data?  Or is the "trouble" not with the fit, but with generating random samples after fitting?

Comment: see my edit with pictures

Comment: The PDF plot is a mess because `data` is not sorted.  Sort the array before you call `lognorm.pdf(data, shape, loc, scale)`.

Comment: Alternatively, generate a new array for the PDF plot. E.g. `x = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 400);  pdf = lognorm.pdf(x, shape, loc, scale); plt.plot(x, pdf)`

Comment: ok great, thanks, that's worked!